# accessing mysql using different server to which db connection data is located

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to include a file with all my db connection info (hostname password username).

this is what i have so far:

```
include ('http://site.com/config35sdf322e54353452d/wp2154654315634652132513546541564.php');

mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");

include ('../refference.php');
$select = mysql_query("SELECT my_field FROM $usertable WHERE ".
"GDI_Username = '$sponsor_GDI_id' AND Unique_id = '$sponsor_refference'");


while($check = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $sponsor_email = $check["email"];
    $sponsor = $check["GDI_Username"];
    $sponsor_first_nme = $check["First_Name"];
    $sponsor_second_nme = $check["Last_name"];
    $sponsor_domain = $check["GDI_Domain"];
    $unq_id = $check["Unique_id"];
 } 

$sponsor_name = "$sponsor_first_nme $sponsor_second_nme";

echo "$sponsor $hostname" ?>
```

I get an error saying it cant select db ("unable to select database")

after some investigating (with the echo statement at the end of the code), it seems to be having issues including the .php file on a different server error code:`include ('http://site.com/config35sdf322e54353452d/wp2154654315634652132513546541564.php');`

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include PHP files from a remote server by enabling the `allow_url_include` function in the php.ini file.

Or you can enable it at runtime by adding this to the top of your script

`ini_set('allow_url_include', 1);`

**However**, this can cause security issues (for instance, it allows an attacker to include a remote file, such a shell)

Answer (score 0):

You can't include your php file from different domain

either

```
 mysql_connect();
```

fails but you have no error handler there

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
```

**$hostname** should be your remote host like **www.remotehost.com** or **192.168.0.100**

**Moreover, your remote host must be configured to accessed remotely**

and as **genesis** said, *"You can't include your php file from different domain"*